# Filemaker: Go to related record from a portal

Tags: filemaker

I have a portal and I want to click one of the items to switch layout and view the record associated with the clicked item.

How do I that?

Comment: never mind, I solved it.

Comment: /How/ did you solve it? with the accepted answer the entire portal becomes a button..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference, the way to do this is as follows:

- Right-click on the portal row and click "Button Setup"
- Choose "Go to Related Record"
- Under Specify, select the table which contains the related record you want to go to
- Select the layout that you would like to display the related record on

You can then limit the related result options if you like.

Comment: Old answer, but it's wrong so I'm correcting it. Using this method you will go to the first record in the portal regardless of what row you click on. The proper approach is to place an invisible rectangle under the objects inside the row border and make this a button with Go to Related Record single step.