# Go to related record from a portal in the same layout

Tags: portal, filemaker

I have a layout which on the left-hand-side is a portal (which is essentially a list of everyone in my address book). When I click on a person in my address book, information is displayed about them on the right-hand-side (using `Go To Related Record`, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974480/in-filemaker-10-go-to-related-record-in-a-portal)).

Unfortunately **every time I click on a person in the portal it resets the portal to the beginning**, so I need to scroll down again if I wanted to click on the next person in the address book!

How can I correct this behaviour so that the portal isn't reset each time I click on the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of alternatives (or perhaps more?):

1) Don't go to related record, but simply set the ID of the person selected into a Global Field, create a relationship that goes from the table instance that the layout is based on and to the address book matching the new Global Field with the ID field in the address book.

2) Rewrite the script that performs the "go to related record" so that is saves the active row numer using Get ( ActivePortalRowNumber ) into a variable before moving to related record and returns to that row number afterwards by using Go To Portal Row < By Calculation >.

Hope this helps!